# Is it Illegal to Share Student Work

Tags: ethics, undergraduate

Is it illegal for professors to make copies of or share student work with other professors without permission? This has happened to me. I thought there was confidentiality in academia but then again nobody follows the law or rules in this world.

Comment: To answer whether or not it is *illegal* would require very detailed knowledge of your local laws (you don't say where you are) as well as any agreements that you have made with your institution. As such you are unlikely to get a definitive answer. You might be able to change this to a more answerable question, such as "how should I respond if my work is shared without permission?" or something along those lines.

Comment: Note that while you may not have given specific permission with respect to that piece of work, at many institutions you sign a general agreement that states that the work you produce while studying is the intellectual property of the university.

Comment: To get a meaningful answer you need to share your location (at least the country) and ideally some specific details about the nature of the work that was shared, who shared it with whom and for what reason.

Comment: If you're in the US, this might be helpful: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Educational_Rights_and_Privacy_Act

Comment: P.S. If there are sensitive details involved, you might want to post from an anonymous account. Your current profile reveals your identity.

Comment: @DanRomik  Thanks for the services. I have deleted my email from my account. This seems sufficient.

Comment: @DanRomik Undergraduate, United States.

Comment: Thanks. It still matters a lot who the work was shared with, and why. The professor who was shown the work might have had a legitimate educational reason to see the papers, in which case it would not be a violation of FERPA (as far as my understanding goes, but IANAL). For example, a professor might show their department chair the paper of a student they suspect of cheating. So, your question still doesn't have enough details to give a meaningful answer I'm afraid.

Comment: @DanRomik I think I have enough details to provide a meaningful answer. It just would have to be a general, academic answer. This is fine; I am not interested in pursuing anyone legally.

Comment: @DanRomik - Why don't you post an answer for the U.S.?  This could at least be useful as a reference point.

Comment: @aparente001 no thanks. As I said, there isn't enough information to give what I would consider a meaningful answer. I'm interested in concrete questions, not in writing prompts for an academic essay. VTC'ed as unclear, but if OP provides more info I may reconsider.

Comment: @Insulin69 - What kind of work was it that was shared?  Was a reason given?

Comment: It is perfectly clear what is being asked.